# Better ways of handling non-numeric character input

Tags: java, swing

Currently working on a small GUI based Java/Swing project which involves converting values from one measurement to another. I am rather new to Swing too.

I am keeping track of how many conversions ("calcCount") the user has done, however count is also incrementing whenever the user inputs a non-numeric character, regardless of if a NumberFormatException is being thrown - i am setting calcCount to zero whenever the conversion fails within the try/Catch, so that shouldn't be happening? (below).

```
try {
conversionFieldValue = Double.parseDouble(text);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  calcCount = 0;
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: the value entered may not be a valid number. \nPlease ensure that you are entering a valid double, with or without a decimal place.", "Conversion error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  conversionCountLabel.setText("Conversion Count: " + calcCount);
}
```

Currently the only place calcCount is being incremented is within the listener for convertButton, which is only being triggered if the value entered isn't empty/null and if the source is convertButton. Code handling that is as follows.

```
if(e.getSource() == convertButton && text.isEmpty() == false) {
   calcCount++;
   conversionCountLabel.setText("Conversion Count: " + calcCount);
}
```

How could i handle this more effectively, and make sure that calcCount is actually incremented in the correct conditions - and not regardless of if parsing fails?

Edit -----------------------

Since i failedto get acorss my problem, i have provided a small program below with the core functiaonlity and the problem i am facing:

class "thing1" - driver class:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class thing1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Thing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        thing2 thing2 = new thing2();

        frame.getContentPane().add(thing2);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

class "thing 2", inluding Extends and relevant listeners

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class thing2 extends JPanel {

    /**
     *  Declaring all variables and components to be used within the GUI
     */
    private JTextField conversionField;
    private JLabel resultLabel, conversionCountLabel, inputLabel;
    private JButton convertButton, clearButton;
    private int calcCount;
    private String text;
    double conversionFieldValue;
    private double result;

    thing2() {

        /**
         * Creating two listeners which will be used
         * "convertListener" is used for conversions
         * "convertDeleteListener" is used to set the values of conversionField, resultLabel, conversionCountLabel and calcCount
         *  all used to display details about number of conversions etc.
         */
        ActionListener convertListener = new ConvertListener();
        ActionListener convertDeleteListener = new convertDeleteListener();

        /**
         *  Creating inputLabel and conversionCountLabel
         */
        inputLabel = new JLabel("Enter value:");
        conversionCountLabel = new JLabel("Conversion Count: ");

        /**
         *  Creating both the convertButon and clearButton
         *  Adding listeners to both buttons which determine when they are clicked,
         *  and what action should be carried out when done so.
         */
        convertButton = new JButton("Convert");
        convertButton.addActionListener(convertDeleteListener);
        convertButton.addActionListener(convertListener); // convert values when pressed
        clearButton = new JButton("Clear");

        /**
         *  Creating both the resultLabel and conversionField
         */
        resultLabel = new JLabel();
        conversionField = new JTextField(5);

        /**
         *  Adding all created assets to the JFrame.
         *  Adding toolTips to each of the created assets.
         *  Adding Listeners to select assets to carry out certain tasks.
         */
        add(inputLabel);
        add(conversionField);
        conversionField.addActionListener(convertListener);
        add(convertButton);
        add(resultLabel);
        add(conversionCountLabel);
        add(clearButton);
        clearButton.addActionListener(convertDeleteListener);

        /**
         *  Creating size of JFrame.
         *  Setting background colour.
         */
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 80));
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public class ConvertListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            /**
             *  Trimming all leading and trailing white spaces from the text the user has input.
             */
            text = conversionField.getText().trim();

            if (text.isEmpty() == false) {
                /**
                 *  Simply trying to convert input to a double, if that fails outputting a Dialog box to users screen stating why
                 */
                try {
                    conversionFieldValue = Double.parseDouble(text);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    calcCount = 0;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: the value entered may not be a valid number. \nPlease ensure that you are entering a valid double, with or without a decimal place.", "Conversion error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    conversionCountLabel.setText("Conversion Count: " + calcCount);
                }


                // the factor applied during the conversion
                double factor = 0;

                // the offset applied during the conversion.
                double offset = 0;

                // Setup the correct factor/offset values depending on required conversion

                result = factor * conversionFieldValue + offset;

                //formatting the value to two decimal places.
                String numAsString = String.format ("%.2f", result);
                resultLabel.setText(numAsString);
            } else {
                if(text.isEmpty() == true) {
                    /**
                     *  if the text value is empty, simply display a dialog box stating so
                     */
                    calcCount = 0;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: the text input area cannot be empty.", "Text area is empty...", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    conversionCountLabel.setText("Conversion Count: " + calcCount);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class convertDeleteListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            /**
             *  Using e.getSource to determine which button was pressed, doing some actions depending on which it was.
             */
            if(e.getSource() == convertButton && text.isEmpty() == false) {
                calcCount++;
                conversionCountLabel.setText("Conversion Count: " + calcCount);
            } else 
                if(e.getSource() == clearButton) {
                    calcCount = 0;
                    conversionField.setText("");
                    resultLabel.setText("");
                    conversionCountLabel.setText("Conversion Count: " + calcCount);
                } 

        }
    }
}
```

Should be able to compile this as is and if you input any character into the field other than a double, you will get an error dialog - however you'lll note "caclCount" still gets incrememented even though the conversion fails. Result will show as 00.00 due to having to cut out the huge switch with all the conversions - this calculates correctly in the full program, just calcCount i am having the issue with.

Edit: This has now been solved, thanks everyone for the help :).

Comment: Seperate your logic into another class/model.  This model should only care about numeric value.  This would require the call to have already converted the values to a correct numeric value before ever interacting with the model.  The model could then take care of both the calculation and the number of operations completed

Comment: You need to show your code "in context" Where is one snippet compared to the other? Basically dont `count++` until you've done a successful conversion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide a small example program that illustrates what you are asking about? The example should be completely self-contained so that anyone can compile and run it.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome @Code-Apprentice  I have edited in an example. Code is as cut down as i could get it, whilst still demonstrating the issue i was trying to originally explain.

Comment: @dstlny I don't have time to look at it right now. In the meantime, you might find the tips at https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ helpful in order to understand the problem better.

Comment: Don't reset **calcCount** to 0 on exceptions or errors within the event. As a matter of fact....remove the line of code ( `calcCount = 0;` ) altogether from those particular blocks. Instead merely Inform the User of the issue, set focus back onto the **conversionField** JTextField with: `conversionField.requestFocus();` then exit the event with a `return;` statement. You could even highlight the suspect text in the JTextField if you like with something like: `conversionField.setSelectionStart(0); conversionField.setSelectionEnd(conversionField.getText().length());`.

Comment: Also, rather than relying on an exception for numerical validity, perhaps use the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method with a [Regular Expression](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html). Something like this: `if (!conversionField.getText().matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) { ...Not valid Code here...}`. This would handle a empty JTextField as well. Handles string representations of signed or unsigned integer or double/float numerical values.

Comment: Thanks for the suggesions everyone! @DevilsHnd - the suggestion of using String#matches() was very useful. The original issue i had was a simple fix that i overlooked (involved changing where **calcCount++** was placed) and i'm using some if's to determine all the possible outcomes (blank textfield, non-numeric etc.) - which work well and trigger on the right conditions! Thanks for the help and suggestions guys!